# Looping through a dictionary and checking each value type

Tags: swift, loops, dictionary, swift2

How do I loop through a dictionary and check for each items *value* type?

Example dictionary:

```
var dict = ([
    "a number" : 1,
    "a boolean" : false,
    "a string" : "Hello"
])
```

My attempts at checking for values:

```
for item in dict.1 {
    if let current = item as? NSNumber {
        print(current)
    }
}
```

and I tried this:

```
for item in settings {
    if item[1] == item[1] as NSNumber {
        print(item)
    }
}
```

**Important note:**

As @Leo pointed out, it's important to keep track of what your dictionary's *value type* is while comparing. The dictionary that I included as my example would be of type `[String : NSObject]` and the dictionary in my project was of type `[String : NSNumber]`. They have to be approached differently!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `is` in swift

```
var dict = ([
    "a number" : 1,
    "a boolean" : false,
    "a string" : "Hello"
])

for (key,value) in dict{
    if value is String{
        println(value)
    }
}
```

Also you can get className

```
for (key,value) in dict{
   println(String.fromCString(object_getClassName(value)))

}
```

This will log

```
Optional("__NSCFString")
Optional("__NSCFNumber")
Optional("__NSCFBoolean")
```

**Update:**

Swift is a **type safe language**,so if you have a dictionary like this

```
var dict = ([
        "a number" : 1,
        "a boolean" : false,
        ])
```

The dict is type of `[String : NSNumber]`,so you do not need to check.

But,if you have a dictionary like this

```
 var dict = ([
        "a number" : 1,
        "a boolean" : false,
        "a string" : "Hello"
        ])
```

Then dict is type of `[String:NSObject]`,in this case you need to check type.

**Update,check if it is Int or Bool**

Better to declare your dictionary to `[String:Any]`
Then

```
      var dict:[String:Any] = ([
        "a number" : 1,
        "a boolean" : false,
        ])

    for (key,value) in dict{
        if value is Bool{
            println(value)
       }
        if value is Int{
            println(value)
        }
    }
```

Comment: yeah, is makes more sense the let as?

Comment: If just want to check value type, I think `is` enough.Because,if it is the type,we do not need to cast. Also,`let as?` is also a good way

Comment: I tried is earlier, and again just now. It throws a warning that says "'is' test is always true" I'm doing it how you've done it in your first code block. except I'm checking for an NSNumber. Any Ideas?

Comment: So what is the final solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

From the swift reference, here is how to iterate over a dictionary

> Iterating Over a Dictionary
>
> You can iterate over the key-value pairs in a dictionary with a for-in
>   loop. Each item in the dictionary is returned as a (key, value) tuple,
>   and you can decompose the tuple’s members into temporary constants or
>   variables as part of the iteration:

```
for (airportCode, airportName) in airports {
        println("\(airportCode): \(airportName)")
    }
    // YYZ: Toronto Pearson
    // LHR: London Heathrow
```

So this should work for your example.

```
var dict = ([
  "a number" : 1,
  "a boolean" : false,
  "a string" : "Hello"
  ])


for (k,v) in dict {
  if let x = v as? NSNumber {
    println("x = \(x)")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use dynamicType to find the class, then use a simple switch statement to take the appropriate action(s)

```
var dict = ([
  "a number" : 1,
  "a boolean" : false,
  "astring" : "Hello"
  ])

for (k,v) in dict {
  switch "\(v.dynamicType)" {
    case "__NSCFString":
      println("found String = \(v)")
    case "__NSCFBoolean":
      println("found Boolean = \(v as! Bool)")
    case "__NSCFNumber":
      println("found Number = \(v)")
    default:break
  }
}
```

Comment: This is really neat. I'm going to make sure to test this out tomorrow. Thanks @nPn, +1

Answer (score 0):

For those who are having issues with warnings, make sure you check your type as @Leo stated above. If your value type is of NSNumber, you'll get errors. If it's of type NSObject use @Leo's or @nPn's answers.

[image]

This is working for me in my project which has a value type of NSNumber:

```
for (key, value) in settings {

    if value == value as Bool {
        print(value)
    }
    if value == value as NSNumber {
        print(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your settings  value is all `NSNumber` type,so it gives you warnings

Comment: You're correct, which is why I selected yours as the answer. I didn't understand that if I included a string in my example that it would change the overall object type. My type in my project is indeed an NSNumber. I've included this as an answer for others in the future who come across the same confusion as I had. Thanks @Leo